# Change white background to an image in bulk

Tags: colors, photoshop, photo, watermark, coreldraw

I have about 10000 photos of shoes with white background behind them.

I want to add tiled logo on each photo instead of the white background, but I don't want to touch the shoes themselves. Only add image instead of white background. I need to do it in bulk.

Are there any watermark softwares or any tools to achieve this? Or how to do it in Photoshop?

In Photoshop there is such a tool to select a color and change it to another color, but it doesn't allow to change the color to an image...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Some might say, you can create an action that fills a new layer with your tiled logo as Pattern, flattens the image & saves it out. And then use that action as a batch process on a folder of images. Some others might say that this isn't a code based question and you need to look at [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: batch process them with action in photoshop - add logo layer and use blend if  to let it show only on pure white area (e.g. 254~255 for under layer). Some questions still not clear: is background pure 255 white? is every photo the same dimension? if not, have to use some trick in action.